# Generate an ordered selectable list on an Excel cell

Tags: excel

Let's say I have a table T1 with the following data:

[image: Table1]

Now, as an input I have another table with only the ref code:

[image]

I would like the green cell to be a selectable list of associated id but ***ordered*** firstly on the status, and secondly on the date (from the closest date).

In this example, I would like to be able to select in the ordered list {3; 4; 1}.

With the ref "B" I would like to be able to select in the ordered list {5; 2}.

As a consequence of the choice of the id I would like to visualize the correspondent data value.

Comment: [this](http://excelsemipro.com/2011/05/a-dynamic-dependent-drop-down-list-in-excel/) might help...

Comment: Thank you, I've read the page but unfortunately I have thousands of ref codes (A, B, C ...) and it is not possible for me to generate manually Dynamic Defined Names for each ref code.

Comment: I have another approach [here](http://www.excel-university.com/create-depdendent-drop-downs-conditional-data-validation/). But in order to use this approach you need to convert your data into Table format and ref column must be sorted. Unfortunately this is the best I can find without using macro. I hope this is good enough for you.

Answer (score 0):

The following solution will limit the user's choices as they fill out the dropdown list. It uses a combination of `Named Ranges`, `Data Validation`, `IF statements`, and `COUNTIF statements` to determine which choices are available.  Order the lists as necessary.

A helper cell with the following formula should be placed on your sheet and referenced by `Data Validation` via the `INDIRECT` function (the formula assumes your dropdown list is in the `range H2:H21`):

```
=IF(COUNTIF($H$2:$H$21,"C")<3,"ABCDE",IF(COUNTIF($H$2:$H$21,"A")<5,"ABDE",IF(COUNTIF($H$2:$H$21,"D")<6,"BDE",IF(COUNTIF($H$2:$H$21,"E")<7,"BE",IF(COUNTIF(H2:H21,"B")<12,"B","N/A")))))
```

First, create a table much like the following to allow `Named Ranges` to be assigned. This table contains all of your criteria and possible choices:

[image]

Assign named ranges for each dropdown list scenario:

[image: image2]

Use `INDIRECT` in the `Data Validation` list reference:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately I have thousands of ref codes (A, B, C ...) and it is not possible for me to generate manually Names Ranges for each ref code...